# Alternative career paths in physics?

Tags: soft-question, education

What do you guys think of alternative career paths in physics away from academia free from the usual academic shackles?

Examples: Garrett Lisi who spends his time surfing and skiing while not working on E<sub>8</sub>.

Or Daniel Bedingham who is able to support himself part-time as an investment banker when not working on quantum mechanics.

Or Julian Barbour who supports himself by translating Russian journal articles into English when not working on quantum gravity.

Is it feasible to count upon Foundational Questions Institute to support such unconventional career paths using Templeton money?

Comment: Look for gossip at your local marketplace and pubs. Voting to close.

Comment: There is an [Academia proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia) in progress, it would be on-topic there.

Answer (score 2):

Before closure, thanks for informing me of the [foundational question institutes '](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FQXi) existence :) .

According to the link :

*It has run two worldwide grant competitions. The first competition provided US $2M to 30 projects*

Any researcher who can compete is free to try for those 30 grants. On the other hand academic and research posts run into the hundreds.